# Access both object and array first element value in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using executesql processor in apache nifi to extract data from a table.

**Table Data**

[image: This is the data of table]

Here in executeSql Processor of nifi after executing the sql query we can get one row of data as output or both the rows based on the given conditions and data present.

**One Row Output**

[image: Data when we have one row as output]

**Two Row Output**

[image: Data when we have two rows as output]

I'm not able to find a way to access the values of the first row excluding the number of rows factor.

After executing SQL Query if the number of rows is more than one then I've to use `$[0].id` value in EvaluateJsonPath processor to get the value of id column of first row and if the output of sql query is one row only then I've to use `$.id` value in EvaluateJsonPath processor to get the value of id column of first row.

Here if the output have multiple rows it gives us arrays of object which can be accessed only using `$[0].id` and if the output have only one row it gives us one object which can be accessed only using `$.id`. Both the scenario can't be handled using `$[0].id`.

Which processor or method should I use so that I can access the data of first row even if the number of rows is 1 only or more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be adding a `JoltTransformJSON` processor just after the current mentioned processor with the following speification

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": { // $[0].id, eg. if there is array of objects
        "id": ""
      },
      "id": "" // $.id, eg. if there is a single object
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The answer you provided was able to modify the whole json data to a single value which is the first value of id column. My scenario was that I need to store the id column first value in attribute of EvaluateJsonPath processor and send rest of the json data further without modifying it. Can you help me with that?